# Commons CLI is not honoring my command line setup

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons-cli

Using [Apache Commons CLI 1.2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) here. I have an executable JAR that needs to take 2 runtime options, `fizz` and `buzz`; both are strings that require arguments/values. I would *like* (if at all possible) my app to be executed like so:

> java -jar myapp.jar -fizz "Alrighty, then!" -buzz "Take care now, bye bye then!"

In this case, the value for the `fizz` option would be "*Alrighty, then!*", etc.

Here's my code:

```
public class MyApp {
    private Options cmdLineOpts = new Options();
    private CommandLineParser cmdLineParser = new GnuParser();
    private HelpFormatter helpFormatter = new HelpFormatter();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyApp myapp = new MyApp();
        myapp.processArgs(args);
    }

    private void processArgs(String[] args) {
        Option fizzOpt = OptionBuilder
            .withArgName("fizz")
            .withLongOpt("fizz")
            .hasArg()
            .withDescription("The fizz argument.")
            .create("fizz");

        Option buzzOpt = OptionBuilder
            .withArgName("buzz")
            .withLongOpt("buzz")
            .hasArg()
            .withDescription("The buzz argument.")
            .create("buzz");

        cmdLineOpts.addOption(fizzOpt);
        cmdLineOpts.addOption(buzzOpt);

        CommandLine cmdLine;

        try {
            cmdLine = cmdLineParser.parse(cmdLineOpts, args);

            // Expecting to get a value of "Alright, then!"
            String fizz = cmdLine.getOptionValue("fizz");
            System.out.println("Fizz is: " + fizz);
        } catch(ParseException parseExc) {
            helpFormatter.printHelp("myapp", cmdLineOpts, true);
            throw parseExc;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following output:

> Fizz is: null

What do I need to do to my code so that my app can be invoked the way I want it to? Or what's the closest I can get to it?

**Bonus points:** If someone can explain to me the difference between the `OptionBuilder`'s `withArgName(...)`, `withLongOpt(...)` and `create(...)` arguments, as I am passing in the same value for them all like so:

```
Option fizzOpt = OptionBuilder
    .withArgName("fizz")
    .withLongOpt("fizz")    }   Why do I have to pass the same value in 3 times to make this work?!?
    .create("fizz");
```

Comment: 1) Your code does not compile (one missing semicolon, not declared exceptions). 2) For me it works. I get the expected `Fizz is: Alrighty, then!`.

Comment: Thanks @Seelenvirtuose (+1) - sorry about the semi-colon (copy n paste bug), I added it. You say it works for you? Can you paste in the exact command-line invocation you're using? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the `.hasArg()` on your OptionBuilder tells it that you expect an argument after the paramter flag.

I got it to work with this command line

```
--fizz "VicFizz is good for you" -b "VicBuzz is also good for you"
```

Using the following code - I put this in the constructor

```
Option fizzOpt = OptionBuilder
        .withArgName("Fizz")
        .withLongOpt("fizz")
        .hasArg()
        .withDescription("The Fizz Option")
        .create("f");

cmdLineOpts.addOption(fizzOpt);
cmdLineOpts.addOption("b", true, "The Buzz Option");
```

**Breakdown**

The option settings are necessary in order to provide more usability on the command line, as well as a nice usage message (see below)

- `.withArgName("Fizz")`: Gives your argument a nice title in the usage
  (see below)
- `.withLongOpt("fizz")`: allows for `--fizz "VicFizz is good for you"`
- `.create("f")`:  is the main parameter and allows
  command line `-f "VicFizz is good for you"`
- Notice that Option b for
  fuzz was constructed much simpler, sacrificing readability during
  usage

**Usage Message**

Personally I love CLI programs that print out a nice usage. You can do this with the `HelpFormatter`.  For example:

```
private void processArgs(String[] args) {
  if (args == null || args.length == ) {
    helpFormatter.printHelp("Don't you know how to call the Fizz", cmdLineOpts);
    ...
```

This will print something usefull like:

```
usage: Don't you know how to call the Fizz
  -b <arg>          The Buzz Option
  -f,--fizz <Fizz>  The Fizz Option
```

Notice how a the short option `-f`, the long option `--fizz`, and a name `<Fizz>` is displayed, along with the description.

Hope this helps